# Is there a "type name" for functions in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers

In C one can define a function pointer, but is there a "type-name" for what's the pointer points to?

To elaborate, instead of `void (*fubar)(void)` could one have a type definition so that one could declare `fubar` as `Frob* fubar`?

Comment: `typedef void(Frob)(void); Frob *fubar;`

Comment: I think it's wrong to link to "Typedef function pointer" as this question is for the pointed to type and not the pointer.

Comment: VTRO.  Dupes referred to a type name to a function pointer.  Here a type name is sought to a function.  Subtle difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no standard type name for function pointers, like there is for `int`. Furthermore, there is no keyword to namespace a tag for them, like there is for `struct`. Instead, you are expected to use `typedef` if you want to refer to a function prototype, or a pointer to a function, by name.

Consider the following `typedef`:

```
typedef void Frob (void);
```

Without the `typedef` keyword, the declaration would be for a prototype of a function named `Frob`. With `typedef`, the name `Frob` is now a type alias for functions that match that prototype. So, it can be used like this:

```
Frob foo;
Frob *fubar = foo;
void foo (void) { puts(__func__); }
int main (void) { fubar(); }
```

In general, `typedef` works this way, where it can turn a variable declaration (sans initializer) into a type alias.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef void (*fubar_p)(void);
```

or

```
void typedef (*fubar_p)(void);
```

or

```
typedef void (fubar)(void);
```

or

```
void typedef (fubar)(void);
```

then you can do

```
fubar_p fun_p;
```

or

```
fubar *fun;
```

In both cases , `fun` and `fun_p` have the same meaning, pointer to function taking no parameter and returning nothing.

Comment: Is the `void typedef (*fubar)(void)` really correct? It looks identical `void typedef (*fubar_p)(void)` except the name.

Answer (score 0):

Just typedef it.

```
typedef void(*Frob)(void);

void f(void)
{
    // your code goes here
}

int main()
{
    Frob fubar = f;
    fubar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. The question was to make `Frob* fubar` define `fubar` to be a function pointer. In your case that would become a pointer to a function pointer.

Comment: Other than the "star", the syntax and behavior are identical.

Comment: And why is that important?